# display route on iOS 7 maps: addOverlay has no effect

Tags: ios, mapkit, ios7, xcode5, mkmapitem

i want display a point to point route inside my mapView, i use this code for create the route:

```
- (IBAction)backToYourCar {
    MKPlacemark *sourcePlacemark = [[MKPlacemark alloc] initWithCoordinate:self.annotationForCar.coordinate addressDictionary:nil];
    NSLog(@"coordiante : locationIniziale %f", sourcePlacemark.coordinate.latitude);
    MKMapItem *carPosition = [[MKMapItem alloc] initWithPlacemark:sourcePlacemark];
    MKMapItem *actualPosition = [MKMapItem mapItemForCurrentLocation];
    NSLog(@"coordiante : source %f, ActualPosition %f", carPosition.placemark.coordinate.latitude ,actualPosition.placemark.coordinate.latitude);
    MKDirectionsRequest *request = [[MKDirectionsRequest alloc] init];
    request.source = actualPosition;
    request.destination = carPosition;
    request.requestsAlternateRoutes = YES;

    MKDirections *directions = [[MKDirections alloc] initWithRequest:request];
    [directions calculateDirectionsWithCompletionHandler:^(MKDirectionsResponse *response, NSError *error) {
        if (error) {
            NSLog(@"Error : %@", error);
        }
        else {
            [self showDirections:response]; //response is provided by the CompletionHandler
        }
    }];
}
```

and this for show the route on the map:

```
- (void)showDirections:(MKDirectionsResponse *)response
{
    for (MKRoute *route in response.routes) {
        [self.mapView addOverlay:route.polyline level:MKOverlayLevelAboveRoads];
    }
}
```

actually this code does nothing.

if i try to print the the distance of route i get the correct value:

```
route distance: 1910.000000
```

then the route is right, but i can't understand why it doesn't appear on the map!

Any suggestions?

Comment: How is `annotationForCar` configured then? You need a coordinate for everything to work...

Comment: Yes, annotationForCar is an MKPointAnnotation and it is correctly displayed on the mapView

Answer (score 50, accepted):

after a day of research i have solved with this 3 steps:

1. Set the delegate (`self.mapView.delegate = self`).
2. import the `MKMapViewDelegate`
3. Implemente the new iOS7 MapView delegate method: 
   `- (MKOverlayRenderer *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView rendererForOverlay(id<MKOverlay>)overlay`:

this is my implementation:

```
- (MKOverlayRenderer *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView rendererForOverlay:(id<MKOverlay>)overlay
{
    if ([overlay isKindOfClass:[MKPolyline class]]) {
        MKPolyline *route = overlay;
        MKPolylineRenderer *routeRenderer = [[MKPolylineRenderer alloc] initWithPolyline:route];
        routeRenderer.strokeColor = [UIColor blueColor];
        return routeRenderer;
    }
    else return nil;
}
```

this method is automatically called by the delegate when you add the polyline on the map.

Comment: When I add MKPolyLine in MKMapView, I am getting bad aceess crash.Detail is here 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18956149/adding-mkpolyline-overlay-to-mkmapview-crashes-application
Can you figure out any solution??

Comment: I was stuck with this, too, because I missed the delegate method. Apple should definitely include this hint in the docs for the [Location and Maps Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/ProvidingDirections/ProvidingDirections.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009497-CH8-SW15).