# MKMapView - rendererForOverlay not called

Tags: ios, mkmapview, mkpolyline

I recently started learning objectiveC and started developing an app in iOS6.

Now, I am trying to convert it for iOS7 and facing issues with MKMap.

In iOS6, I was using viewForOverlay.

In iOS7, I am changing it to renderForOverlay. But, my application is not calling mapView:rendererForOverlay. Below is my code. Appreciate your help.

```
- (void) drawPolyline:(NSArray *)locations
{
    [mapView setDelegate:self];
    ...
    ...

    self.polyline = [MKPolyline polylineWithCoordinates:locationCoordinate2DArray count:numberOfLocations];
    free(locationCoordinate2DArray);
    [mapView addOverlay:self.polyline];
    [mapView setNeedsDisplay];
}

- (MKOverlayRenderer*)mapView:(MKMapView*)mapView rendererForOverlay:(id <MKOverlay>)overlay
{
    MKPolylineRenderer* lineView = [[MKPolylineRenderer alloc] initWithPolyline:self.polyline];
    lineView.strokeColor = [UIColor blueColor];
    lineView.lineWidth = 7;
    return lineView;
}
```

Comment: program not calling mapView:rendererForOverlay

Answer (score 17):

I am assuming that you did declare the `MKMapViewDelegate` delegate in your header file via the `@interface` statement:

However, did you assign the delegate in the `viewDidLoad` (or where you think its appropriate) method?

```
self.mapView.delegate = self;
```

Comment: Yes, I have the delegate in header file... @interface MapTrackerViewController : UIViewController <MKMapViewDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate>
{
    MKMapView *mapView;
    ...
}                                                                                   I have delegate assigned in drawPolyline method ([mapView setDelegate:self];). Please find the code in my original post. It was working in iOS6. In iOS7, they removed viewforOverlay method. Now, I am trying to implement rendererForOverlay. But it doesn't get called.

Answer (score 2):

Like others have said, be sure you set your `delegate` before adding them. Use the `addOverlay:level:` method since `addOverlay:` will be deprecated (according to the comment in the header).

My issue was something dumb. I had lat and long switched by mistake for my polygon's points. Be sure to double check that if they still aren't showing up.

You might also try logging `pointCount` on your polygon to make sure they are being set properly.

Related, this is how to do it in Swift:

```
// Get your coordinates from somewhere as an [CLLocationCoordinate2D] array
// If you already have them, make a local mutable copy
var coordinates = [CLLocationCoordinate2D]()

// Create your polygon
let polygon = MKPolygon(coordinates: &coordinates, count: coordinates.count)
```

Hopefully this saves you some time!

Comment: thanks! same dumb problem here. I was switching the latitudes and longitudes... !

Comment: Omg! I did the same thing. Ugh there goes 2 hours of my life. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

OK, I had the same issue and finally found the case.
We have to use `[MKMapView addOverlay: level:]` instead of `[MKMapView addOverlay:]`.
It triggers `rendererForOverlay` rather than `viewForOverlay` of the delegate.
Hope this would be helpful for you iOS 7 lovers!

Comment: Well, I also had another case and I override MKMapView and it relays all the delegate methods such as mapView: viewForOverlay: And I had to add another relay of mapView: rendererForOverlay:

Answer (score 1):

If there is only one point in `locationCoordinate2DArray,mapView:rendererForOverlay` would not be called.

Answer (score 0):

I just finished my experiments with this method and I found that only **nib-file placed MKMapView** and `@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet MKMapView *mapView;` fixed this issue. Also here is [checklist](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18817934/1717401).

Answer (score 0):

For me, the solution involved two steps:

1. Set the delegate first, before adding the overlay. As soon as the overlay is added, the delegate methods will be called.
2. Check the delegate. Stupidly, I had a local property called delegate in my code. In iOS 6, it didn't matter, in iOS 7 it did. As soon as I removed that stray delegate, rendererForOverlay: got called.

Answer (score 0):

Just a hint for such like me, which struggle with IOS 13 on that. It looks, as IOS 13 ignores something like:

```
// self is a MKTileOverlayRenderer
// the code is called, if a method has produced a tile for a given MKMapRect

// tell the system that we are ready
DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {

    // invalidate the mapRect
    self.setNeedsDisplay(mapRect)

})
```

This code worked fine in IOS 10 - IOS 12, but now you have to add the zoomScale to the setNeedsDisplay(), otherwise it seems to be ignored by IOS 13... cost me 4 hours to sort it out ;-)

```
self.setNeedsDisplay(mapRect, zoomScale: zoomScale)
```